# Regular Expression OR (|) how does it work?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to get the pipe (OR) to work.  I have this regular expression with these tests:

```
   string output = "test: {0} matches";
   string test = "AND [Field] =";

   Regex r = new Regex(@"AND|OR\s[?\w+]?\s?=");

   if (r.IsMatch(test)) 
      Console.WriteLine(string.Format(output, test));

   test = "OR [Field] =";
   if (r.IsMatch(test))
      Console.WriteLine(string.Format(output, test));
```

The first match passes but the second fails.  I can't figure out why the | between the AND and OR does not act like an OR statement.  I've tried putting parenthesis around the AND|OR but then both test fails.

Can anyone help me with the OR "|" statement please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within regex, alternation (`|`) has lower precedence than sequence. Your regex pattern is interpreted as “`AND` or (`OR` followed by `\s[?\w+]?\s?=`)” (note the parenthesis I added to denote precedence).

To achieve what you want, you’ll need to parenthesize your `AND|OR` part, as well as escape your `[` and `]` characters.

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"(AND|OR)\s\[?\w+\]?\s?=");
```

Furthermore, you probably do not want to allow an `[` without a `]` (or vice versa); either both should be present, or neither:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"(AND|OR)\s(\[\w+\]|\w+)\s?=");
```

Comment: Thanks.  I forgot about the matching braces.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to putting parenthesis around (AND|OR), you also need to escape [ and ]:

```
(AND|OR)\s\[?\w+\]?\s?=
```